# Issue setting html of element via jQuery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, date

I have a td with a class name of "seminar_date_time" that I'm trying to set the inner html of after converting a datetime into a string format that I want. Here's my code...

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $seminar_date, $am_pm, $room, $building, $speaker_lname, $speaker_fname, $title);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
            <script>
                var date_object = new Date("<?php echo $seminar_date; ?>");

                var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                var month = monthNames[date_object.getMonth()];
                var day = date_object.getDay();
                var year = date_object.getFullYear();
                var hour = date_object.getHours();
                var mins = date_object.getMinutes();
                var time_string = null;
                var ampm = null;

                if(hour > 12) {
                    hour -= 12;
                    ampm = "PM";
                }
                else {
                    ampm = "AM";
                }

                if(mins === 0) {
                    mins = "00";
                }

                time_string = `${hour}:${mins} ${ampm}`;

                // using ES6 string template literal for date string
                var date_string = `${month} ${day}, ${year} at ${time_string}`;

                console.log(`date and time: ${date_string}`);

                                $(".seminar_date_time").html(date_string);
            </script>
            <tr class="clickable_row" data-href="seminar_attendance.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td class="seminar_date_time"></td>
                <td><?php echo $room; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $building; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$speaker_lname, $speaker_fname"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

When I render this to the page the date string in that td is the same for every row. When I console.log() my newly formed date string, it logs it perfect every time. The next line after that console.log() is setting the html via jQuery on the td with class name "seminar_date_time".

I know the php code is being set server side, so I'm guessing there's a racing problem between setting the server side content and setting the jQuery client side?

How can I get my new date string into each row's td correctly?

---

**EDIT:**

It sounds like the consensus here is that I need to be formatting the date in PHP instead of doing it through JS. That is what I plan to do now, but maybe these answers could still help someone else that needs to mix PHP and JS in this way. Thank you to all that answered.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you declare in the `<script>` tag are global variables, they are not scoped to the current entry in the loop. This means that when you add several such script tags you end up changing the variable, not creating a new one. What you need to do is create a scope for the variables to live in that isn't global.

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $seminar_date, $am_pm, $room, $building, $speaker_lname, $speaker_fname, $title);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
            <script>
            (function(){
                var date_object = new Date("<?php echo $seminar_date; ?>");

                var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                var month = monthNames[date_object.getMonth()];
                var day = date_object.getDay();
                var year = date_object.getFullYear();
                var hour = date_object.getHours();
                var mins = date_object.getMinutes();
                var time_string = null;
                var ampm = null;

                if(hour > 12) {
                    hour -= 12;
                    ampm = "PM";
                }
                else {
                    ampm = "AM";
                }

                if(mins === 0) {
                    mins = "00";
                }

                time_string = `${hour}:${mins} ${ampm}`;

                // using ES6 string template literal for date string
                var date_string = `${month} ${day}, ${year} at ${time_string}`;

                console.log(`date and time: ${date_string}`);

                $(".seminar_date_time").html(date_string);
            }());
            </script>
            <tr class="clickable_row" data-href="seminar_attendance.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td class="seminar_date_time"></td>
                <td><?php echo $room; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $building; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$speaker_lname, $speaker_fname"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```

This should work for you.

But, I have to comment that this is not the best way to mix php and JavaScript. You should try to do all of this in php only, rather than mix it on the frontend and backend.

Comment: Really?  Add the same javascript code over and over again for each seminar?  Don't get me wrong, this will work, but this is not a very good solution...

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll try to do all the date conversions in PHP instead

Answer (score 0):

Not a race condition, no.  It is because you are adding the same javascript over and over again, overriding `date_string` every time, then replacing all of the matching `$(".seminar_date_time")`'s content with the newest `date_string`

A better solution would be to create an array of the individual dates and only add the javascript *once*, after the loop, as a *function*, then adding the array as a new javascript object and running the function on each array element.

Or, if you are already doing processing and building out the html in PHP... *just do it all in the PHP*, that way the date is correct to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'll try to do all the date conversions in PHP instead

Answer (score 0):

You have not to expose such processing to frontend via javascript. But with js here is my variant:

```
<?php
if($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $seminar_date, $am_pm, $room, $building, $speaker_lname, $speaker_fname, $title);
?>
    <script>
            (function() {
                var fn_date_string = function(dt) {
                    var date_object = new Date(dt);

                    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                    var month = monthNames[date_object.getMonth()];
                    var day = date_object.getDay();
                    var year = date_object.getFullYear();
                    var hour = date_object.getHours();
                    var mins = date_object.getMinutes();
                    var time_string = null;
                    var ampm = null;

                    if(hour > 12) {
                        hour -= 12;
                        ampm = "PM";
                    }
                    else {
                        ampm = "AM";
                    }

                    if(mins === 0) {
                        mins = "00";
                    }

                    time_string = `${hour}:${mins} ${ampm}`;

                    // using ES6 string template literal for date string
                    var date_string = `${month} ${day}, ${year} at ${time_string}`;

                    return date_string;
                };
                $(function () {
                    // DOM is fully loaded
                    $(.seminar_date_time).each(function () {
                        $(this).html(fn_date_string($(this).data('dt'));
                    }
                });
            })();
    </script>
?>
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
            <tr class="clickable_row" data-href="seminar_attendance.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td class="seminar_date_time" data-dt="<?php echo $seminar_date; ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $room; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $building; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$speaker_lname, $speaker_fname"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```